# Reload Activity after every 2 minutes

Tags: android

I want to reload my activity after every 1 minute. I tried using handler for this... but problem is that when i press back key of device, it doesn't stop and goes into an infinite loop..

here is my code what i have done--

```
public class Chat extends Activity {
    Handler handler;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.chat);
        handler = new Handler();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "again", 400).show();

        doTheAutoRefresh();
    }

    private void doTheAutoRefresh() {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                //doTheAutoRefresh();                
            }
        }, 10000);
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you just want to refresh the data?

Comment: If you have a chat, don't poll the server every minute. Read about sockets, you can use some push solution (GCM) to update your content in the app

Answer (score 0):

You should do this to remove all handler's messages and callbacks:

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}
```